# links not clickable in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, hyperlink, click

I can't click on some of the links and text boxes in the #header of my website in IE8 (works otherwise fine in modern browsers)

See: http://www.ekgquiz.dk

I have tried those solutions without any success.
Sometimes i can click the links during loading time.

[In IE only text part of link is clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650468/in-ie-only-text-part-of-link-is-clickable)
[Link is clickable sometimes on page load, other times not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752567/link-is-clickable-sometimes-on-page-load-other-times-not-clickable)
[IE8 - navigation links not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841842/ie8-navigation-links-not-working)

Thanks in advance for your help!
Antoine